# 3x 100 gallon propane tank on 3 family building

Tags: heating, hot-water, propane, tankless

I'm a new owner of a 3 family apartment building with 3 100 gallon propane tanks for heating and hot water for each unit. All 3 units have Navien tankless hot water heaters. I'm thinking about getting rid of the 3rd floor tank and converting that unit to a different source for heat and hot water because of the very small unit size. Would I be able to remove a empty tank from another unit and just replace it with the 3rd floor tank that still has propane in the tank? Disconnect 3rd floor full tank and reconnect tank to 2nd floor unit. I would rather use the full tank on another unit that has a empty tank.

Comment: do you have a crane to lift

Comment: I think transporting a full tank will be extremely difficult and dangerous. Both moving it around the property and also transporting it by road, *for which you probably do not have the certifications or permits*.  Best to use up the gas on site, but if you must drain it, talk to your fuel supplier, they should be able to help you empty the tank for transport.

Comment: why are you moving tanks. Why not running new piping.

Comment: Why mess with it? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you own the tanks or are they leased from the gas company?

Comment: @Harper - where, exactly, does the question say ANYTHING about transporting the tank by road??? If these are the usual tanks I grew up with, they can be tipped and rolled or moved with a handcart by a competent person - we had to get 4 before winter and swap them out (2-tank valve) becasue the snow prevented them being delivered/changed by the gas company in winter. Presumably the gas company will come pick up the empty in their truck that they use to drop off the fulls and collect the empties with.

Comment: I don't own one, but it seems to me a 100-gallon propane tank is the kind that is typically *delivered* and swapped, rather than filled in place.  No?   It weighs 200 pounds, full, less than many things that are routinely moved into, out of, and around apartments by "movers".    I'm not sure what is the question here.  What does "Would I be able ...." mean?

Comment: Typically the three tanks would be kept together on the ground outside.  Are you saying these are kept *in the units*?  The 3rd floor tank is on the third floor, inside the apartment?

Comment: I've seen 100 pound tanks filled in place - it depends on the gas company how they want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming you have a normal arrangement with your fuel company, either you or they can do this - if they normally come and swap tanks, they might be happier if you let them do it, reducing the odds of screwing up and causing a leak. Best to contact them first.

*I would, however, sincerely doubt that you'll get a reasonable return on investment for swapping fuel sources (buying new appliances, etc.) if the apartment has working appliances that run on LP.*

Answer (score 0):

It is not so much whether you can, more about whether you *may*.

The propane in every tank is the same substance, so yeah it's *possible*.

The thing you have to worry about is if you have the necessary qualifications to mess with the propane supply on a multi-dwelling structure.